# JUnit plugin integration

Tags: eclipse, junit, rcp

Is there a way to integrate in an Eclipse RCP project the JUnit Window? I am planning on creating a test script runner and I want JUnit window to be in my application.

Comment: not really. It just triggers junit test to be run. Not putting the JUnit window plugin inside an RCP.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but not as you expect it. The JUnit view is contributed by org.eclipse.jdt.junit (which you can see by hitting Shift-Alt-F1 with that view being active). So you need to include that as a dependency in your plugin (or in your product definition, if you have one).

The bad news: I have not checked the dependencies for that plugin, and those dependencies will probably take most of the JDT into your application also, which is probably not desired.